# Does geopandas handle shapefiles (in lat/lon) that straddle the anti-meridian properly?

Tags: geopandas, shapely, fiona

I have been looking for a way to check if a point lies within a shapefile. i had some code that worked for the most part (using shapely and fiona) but my understanding is that it will exhibit unintended behaviour if it straddles the antimeridian. My question is does geopandas account for the antimeridian when checking if a lat/lon pair lies within a shapefile?

Comment: According to one of the answers to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226605/shapely-polygons-crossing-the-antimeridian, you can expect "undesirable behavior"

Comment: yeah i have looked at that question, i just would really like to get a definitive answer. not much about this on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Given that https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/448#issuecomment-538419131 is still an open issue (with listed workarounds in the linked comment), geopandas is not "antimeridian-aware".